# It is possible to inject headers in PHP mail() $to argument?

Tags: php, security

I was wondering if this code is secure or not,

```
$mail = mail($_POST['email'], 'foo' , 'foo');
```

It was reported as insecure by RIPS.

Comment: You could basically send mail to anyone from your server. It can be abused by spammers.

Comment: putting a $_POST into anything is not a wise choice, always sanitize your inputs!

Comment: When quoting a security advisory, please link to it or quote from it. It will never contain just "this is insecure", but an exact description of what the problem is and in which versions of the language it occurs.

Comment: @Pekka웃 - there won't be an advisory link in this case because RIPS is security scanner application that you would run against your own code -- see http://rips-scanner.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @SDC ah, fair enough.

Answer (score 3):

As others have already said, using `mail($_POST['email']...)` is insecure for several reasons before you even start to think about header injection attacks.

Allowing a POST variable to be used as the 'To' address is insecure because your form could be used to send mail to anyone. Even if a spammer couldn't get their message into the body text, it could still be used to attack someone by blasting their mailbox with thousands of messages.

Secondly, you haven't shown us whether your `$_POST['email']` variable has been sanitised or not. You should check that it is a valid email address before using it as one. Otherwise, yes, it could be used to cause mischief for your mailer. Luckily, PHP has an email validation function built-in:

```
$sanitisedEmail = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
if(!$sanitisedEmail) {die('your email address is invalid');}
```

But aside from anything else, if you want to avoid header injection attacks, you should avoid using PHP's `mail()` function entirely. The build-in `mail()` function is extremely basic and has many weaknesses that can be exploited by hackers. You would be *far* better off using a good quality wrapper library such as [phpMailer](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/).

phpMailer's main purpose is to make sending emails much simpler in PHP -- the PHP code required to use the standard `mail()` function can get very messy if you need to start adding headers or attachments; phpMailer makes all of this very easy.

But in addition, using it will also make your code more secure; phpMailer does all the necessary input sanitisation for you; it validates email addresses and strips malicious header attacks as part of it's standard process.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Surely it's not secure and vulnerable to mail injection. Why do you ask?

SMTP protocol is very simple and very close to HTTP one.
It contains headers and each header separatted from another by a mere newline. 
So, having  $_POST['email'] equal to

```
foo@example.com
To: bar@example.com
```

your script will send 2 mails.
The same goes for almost every argument, including Subject.

Also, just like in HTTP, headers separated from the body by an empty line.
So, the attacker may also **rewrite the body** as well

To prevent that, just check user-entered fields ('cept for the body of course), for `\n` and `\r` characters.

Comment: Excuse me for my poor explanation, I'm just interested in header injection: does PHP santize $to against header injection?

Answer (score -1):

A malicious user cannot inject headers, but he can pass a long, long, long string of comma separated email addresses and use your service for spamming.

You should always perform checks on your user input data before using them in a function (or in whatever you need)!